How did they remove the Angular component wrapper element in Clarity
I noticed that the button of Clarity design system does not contain a wrapper element in the DOM. I like this for various reasons (clarity - no pun intended, accessibility).
I've looked around for solutions to do such a thing. Some solutions risk impacting Angulars change detection and other mechanics.
The solution Clarity chose seems very clean. But I can't get it to work: best result I managed was to still get the wrapper element and the contents placed as sibling in the DOM.
Here is Clarity's code for the button:
https://github.com/vmware-clarity/ng-clarity/blob/main/projects/angular/src/button/button-group/button.ts
And this is how it renders:

As far as I can see how they did it:

put component contents in a ng-template with a ref
link the ref to a viewchild

@Component({
  selector: 'clr-button',
  template: `
    <ng-template #buttonProjectedRef>
      <button

export class ClrButton implements LoadingListener {
  @Output('click') _click = new EventEmitter<boolean>(false);

  @ViewChild('buttonProjectedRef', { static: true }) templateRef: TemplateRef<ClrButton>;


Strangely I can't see where the property name of the viewchild ("templateRef") is being used.

They probably used the renderer to replace the host tag name and if so, that is not the best idea. You could use a component as an attribute selector on a button like angular material does, which is a better idea, because when you replace the host tag, the element does not get destroyed automatically by angular and you have to take care of that yourself. Also structural directives like *ngIf might break.

Actually the button component has its own selector clr-button but this will not work on its own, it requires a parent component clr-button-group.
In the demos, this is how they are using it
  <clr-button-group>
    <clr-button>1</clr-button>
    <clr-button>2</clr-button>
    <clr-button>3</clr-button>
    <clr-button [clrInMenu]="true">4</clr-button>
    <clr-button [clrInMenu]="true">5</clr-button>
    <clr-button [clrInMenu]="true">6</clr-button>
  </clr-button-group>

So the buttons exist inside the Content Children
So the button groups takes a content child, of all the buttons first
Button Group Ts
export class ClrButtonGroup implements AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input('clrToggleButtonAriaLabel') clrToggleButtonAriaLabel: string = this.commonStrings.keys.rowActions;

  @ViewChild('menuToggle') menuToggle: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  @ViewChild('menu') menu: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  @ContentChildren(ClrButton) buttons: QueryList<ClrButton>; // this line here!

After that processing happens and the buttons gets pushed to menuButtons, then finally a loop is done over the buttons and rendered using ng-template
Button Group HTML
<ng-template *ngFor="let menuButton of menuButtons" [ngTemplateOutlet]="menuButton.templateRef"></ng-template>


But surely they still manage to render just a <button> tag for buttons that aren't part of a group? Maybe I linked to the wrong ts file in Clarity? I thought that one was a 'standalone' button.

@KoertvanKleef please share the example where this happens on github please

Looking at their Storybook stories they have examples where button is being used as ClrButton: https://github.com/vmware-clarity/ng-clarity/blob/main/.storybook/stories/button/button.stories.ts. In those stories the selector seems to be simply button as a tag. The button-group/button.ts (https://github.com/vmware-clarity/ng-clarity/blob/main/projects/angular/src/button/button-group/button.ts) states tag selector clr-button but those too simply render <button> in the DOM.

@KoertvanKleef They are doing the same thing, they define the button, add a ref #buttonRef then use it to render inside ng-template they are doing the long way, if they dont want the selector, they should just define the component with a class selector .cls-button or a attribute selector [clsButton] this is the simpler way to achieve what you want!

I'm not quite sure I understand. If the button-group/button.ts component (with selector clr-button) is used in the button stories then how can angular know those <button>'s are actually clr-button? Since the button doesn't match the clr button selector.

@KoertvanKleef So they are not the button you are taking about, they are just normal buttons, this clr-button cannot exist without its own selector <clr-button/>

I think I understand. So the buttons that are part of buttongroup are able to be rendered as button beceause the buttongroup renders their contents (thus omitting the wrapper) and the standalone buttons are simply html buttons with css?

@KoertvanKleef Yes exactly, do try out my suggestion for different component selectors, they dont create unnecessary elements too!
